# understanding regex if then statements

Tags: java, regex

So I'm not sure if I understand how this works and would like
**`a simple explanation to how they work`** is all. I probably have it way off. **`A pure regex solution is required, and I don't know if this is possible`**. If it is, a solution would be awesome too, but a shove in the right direction would be good for my learning process `^_^`

This is how I thought the `if/then/else` option built into my regex engines was formatted:

```
?(condition)if regex|else regex
```

I want it to capture a string from a very specific location only when this string exists within a certain section of javascript. Because this is how I thought it worked after a decent amount of research I tried out a few variations of this code but they all ended up something like this.

```
((?^view_large$)Tables-137(.*?)search.htm)
```

**`Also of relevance: I'm using an java based app that has regex searches which pull the data I need so I cannot write an if statement in java which would be my preferred method.`** It's a pain to have to do it this way, but at the moment I have no other choice. I'm trying really hard for them to allow java code functionality instead of pure regex for more versatile options.

So to summarize, **`is there even a if/then option in regex and if so how is it formatted for what I'm trying to accomplish?`**

**EDIT: The string that I want to be the "if condition" is like this: if `view_large` string exists and is not null then capture the exact string `500/` which is captured within the catch all group I used: `(.*?)`**

Comment: Can you give an example of what you're searching for and what you have to match and return?  Is there some reason lookaheads and lookbehinds won't work?

Comment: Can you give examples of input - and desired outcomes for 'regexing' these inputs?

Comment: Done and done. I always leave out info on accident :(

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no conditionals in Java regexp, but you can simulate them by writing two expressions that include mutually exclusive [*look-behind constructs*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), like this:

```
((?<=if )then)|((?<!if )end)
```

This expression will match "then" when it is preceded by an `"if "`; it will match `"end"` when it is *not* preceded by an `"if "`

Comment: awesome this is exactly what I want it to do. What would I do if the `"if"` has to be an exact string?

Comment: @TravisDtfsuCrum In my example `"if "` is the exact string. For example, this expression `((?<=a)b)|((?<!a)c)` will match `b` if there's `a` in front of it, or `c` if there's anything except `a` in front of it.

Comment: awesome, perfect perfect perfect. Wasn't sure if it took the input in a look-behind construct as literal or like any other regex

Comment: would a lookahead be formatted like this then? `((?=if )then)|((?!if )end)`

Comment: @TravisDtfsuCrum Look-behind expressions can take literals, but are not limited to them: for example, `(?<=[a-f])x` would be a valid regexp, matching `x` when it is preceded by `a`, `b`, `c`, `d`, or `f`.

Comment: @TravisDtfsuCrum Lookaheads are placed after the expression, not before it, so your expression would be `(then(?=if ))|(end(?!if ))`

Comment: Ok thanks man for all the help. This actually saved me a ton of time

Comment: See http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html for more information about lookahead and lookbehind. Note in particular that lookbehind usually doesn't allow repetition or optional items.

Answer (score 2):

[The Javadoc for `java.util.regex.Pattern`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) mentions, in its list of "Perl constructs not supported by this class":

> - The conditional constructs `(?(condition)X)` and `(?(condition)X|Y)`.

So, no dice. But you should look through the Javadoc to see if you can achieve what you need by using regex features that it *does* support. (Or, if you post some more detailed examples, we can try to help.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, the websites with tutorials I read gave me the impression that it existed but what not sure since nothing I was trying worked

Answer (score 1):

Try lookaround assertions.

For example, say you want to capture FOOBAR only if there is a 4+ digit number somewhere:

```
(?=.*\d{4}).*(FOOBAR)
```

Comment: Thanks for the input, I wasn't sure if lookarounds would do what I wanted since I'm pretty new to regex. Especially when it comes to using pure regex solutions