# Java conditional regex to check 24 hour time?‽

Tags: java, regex, string, testing, time

I am doing the following programming exercise: [regex validation of 24 hours time.](https://www.codewars.com/kata/56a4a3d4043c316002000042) The statement is:

> Write a regex to validate a 24 hours time string. See examples to
>   figure out what you should check for:
>
> Accepted: 01:00 - 1:00
>
> Not accepted:
>
> 24:00
>
> You should check for correct length and no spaces.

I would like to ask, why the following regular expression, matches 24:00

```
public class RegexValidation {
  public static boolean validateTime(String time) {
    System.out.println("time: "+time);
    return time.matches("(?:^[2])[0123]+:[0-5]+[0-9]|[0-9]+:[0-5]+[0-9]");
  }
}
```

Because I thought it was expressing:
"If string starts with 2, then it should continue with [0-3] (one or more) : [0-5] one or more and [0-9]. Else it continues with [0-9] one or more : [0-5] one or more and [0-9]."

The tests are:

```
import org.junit.Test;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

public class RegexValidationTest {

  @Test
  public void test1() {
    assertTrue(RegexValidation.validateTime("01:00"));
  }

  @Test
  public void test2() {
    assertTrue(RegexValidation.validateTime("1:00"));
  }

  @Test
  public void test3() {
    assertTrue(RegexValidation.validateTime("00:00"));
  }

  @Test
  public void test4() {
    assertFalse(RegexValidation.validateTime("13:1"));
  }

  @Test
  public void test5() {
    assertFalse(RegexValidation.validateTime("12:60"));
  }

  @Test
  public void test6() {
    assertFalse(RegexValidation.validateTime("24:00"));
  }
}
```

In addition I wrote the following solution, which passes the tests:

```
public class RegexValidation {
  public static boolean validateTime/*⌚*/(String time) {
    if(time.matches("[\\d]+:[\\d]{2}")){
      String[] times = time.split(":");
      int hours = Integer.parseInt(times[0]);
      int minutes = Integer.parseInt(times[1]);
      return hours < 24 && minutes < 60;
    }
    return false;
  }
}
```

I have also read:

- [Conditional Regular Expression in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3687921/conditional-regular-expression-in-java)
- https://www.regular-expressions.info/conditional.html
- [understanding regex if then statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12691404/understanding-regex-if-then-statements)

Finally the question is, why in the first code the regex matches 24:00?‽

Comment: The pattern matches `24:00` due to the alternation `|`. If the first part does not match, then `[0-9]+:[0-5]+[0-9]` will match `24:00` The pattern can be written as `^2[0123]+:[0-5]+[0-9]|[0-9]+:[0-5]+[0-9]` and will also match for example `24:59` or `99:50` but not `24:60`

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1494671/regular-expression-for-matching-time-in-military-24-hour-format for possible solutions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because of the `|` present. The alternative after this, `[0-9]+` matches any digit from 1 to 9, and breaks the required output.

The [following regex](https://regex101.com/r/0r2Hzm/2) should work,

```
^([01]\d|[0-9]|2[0-3]):?([0-5]\d)$
```

If the `:` is not optional, remove the `?`

```
^([01]\d|[0-9]|2[0-3]):([0-5]\d)$
```

Also verified on `jshell`

```
jshell> var pattern = Pattern.compile("^([01]\\d|[0-9]|2[0-3]):?([0-5]\\d)$");
pattern ==> ^([01]\d|[0-9]|2[0-3]):?([0-5]\d)$

jshell> pattern.matcher("23:01").matches();
$2 ==> true

jshell> pattern.matcher("24:01").matches();
$3 ==> false

jshell> pattern.matcher("00:01").matches();
$4 ==> true

jshell> pattern.matcher("09:01").matches();
$5 ==> true

jshell> pattern.matcher("9:01").matches();
$6 ==> true

jshell> pattern.matcher("12:00").matches();
$7 ==> true
```